# flowplayer $("#element").flowplayer() not working in safari

Tags: html, video, safari, flowplayer

I am trying to make a html5 flowplayer out of a div, but it is not working in Safari(latest version, probably on older versions too). Even in IE it works.

Here is the js code:

```
$("#fplayer").flowplayer({
    play : true,
    engine:  'html5',
    fullscreen : false,
    playlist : [
    // A list of type-url mappings in picking order
    [{
        mp4 : defaults.url
    }, {
        webm : "http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm"
    }, {
        ogg : "http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.ogv"
    }]]
    , cuepoints: defaults.cuepoints
});
```

There are no errors in the Safari developer console. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does flowplayer not display a custom error?

Comment: Where should I look for this custom error?

Comment: Normally when flowplayer fails to load/play a video it displays an error message on the page where the video would be.